# Inequality in statistics problem. Is my solution correct?

Tags: statistics, inequality, solution-verification

1. Probability of damaging an element in time $T$ equals $0.2$ How many such elements should there be so at least 50 won't be damaged after time T with probability 0.9, 0.95 and 0.99.

So from what I understand I should solve this: 
$\sum_{k = 50}^{n}  {n \choose k} * \left( 1 - p \right)^k * p^{n-k} > 0.95$ ?
And two more inequalities $.95$ and $.99$ ? 
To be honest it's a total guess and if it's correct could someone explain it shortly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we start with $n$ items. Let $X$ be the number of undamaged items after time $T$. Then $X$ has binomial distribution, with $p=0.8$.

We want $\Pr(X\ge 50)\approx 0.9$. (And later, we could use the same basic technique tp solve the problems with $0.95$ and $0.99$, three different problems, three different answers.)

The random variable $X$ has mean $0.8n$, and variance $(0.8)(0.2)n$, and therefore standard deviation $(0.4)\sqrt{n}$.

Using the normal approximation to the binomial, we want 
$$\Pr\left(Z\gt \frac{50-0.8n}{(0.4)\sqrt{n}}\right)\approx 0.9.$$
Using tables, we find that we want
$$ \frac{50-0.8n}{(0.4)\sqrt{n}}\approx -1.28.$$
Rewrite this as 
$$0.8n-0.512\sqrt{n}-50\approx 0.$$
This is a quadratic equation in $\sqrt{n}$. Solve using the Quadratic Formula. We get $\sqrt{n}\approx 8.232$. Square. We get about $67.76$.

We have used an approximation. Presumably something like $68$ is about right. One could calculate exactly, using the binomial distribution and software, to get an exact answer. Not that exact is all that important, since in the real world $0.2$ may be a crude estimate.

Comment: Are you sure about the answer? Because my professor told us that $n \ge 68$

Comment: Yeah, you made a little mistake on multiplying $0.4 * -1.28$. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for the arithmetic fix. Those little decimal points are slippery.